# React Native first time user stacknavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have a stacknavigator with a intro screen and a login screen.

```
export const StackerIntro = createStackNavigator({ 
  Intro: {
    screen: Intro,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    }
  }, {
 InitialRouteName: "Intro"
})
```

How can I make the initial route be `"Login"` if it isnt the users first time in the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For conditional rendering you might have to use `switchNavigation`.

1 .Save the key in async storage if the user logs in for the first time.

2. When the user comes again for the second time, get the key in navigation class using `async-await` and if you get the key then navigate to the desired location or else navigate to login.
3. Use [SwitchNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html) for conditional navigation.

You can also try :

```
    const routeName = () => {
      var routeName =
        global.isSignUpScreen == false || global.isSignUpScreen == undefined
          ? "LoginScreen"
          : "SignUpScreen";
      console.log("routeName >> " + routeName);
      return routeName;
    };


    const SignUpStack = createStackNavigator(
      {
        LoginScreen: {
          screen: LoginScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            header: null
          }
        },
        SignUpScreen: {
          screen: SignUpScreen,
          }
      {
        initialRouteName: routeName()
      }
}
    );
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I ended up using `SwitchNavigation` and I followed their auth-flow.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to set initialroute to be login. all you need to do is store a value in asyncstorage when the app is opened for the first time and for the second time when it comes to app.js check if that value is there are not. if its there then you need to go to login else go to intro.

Ex:

```
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("installSucess");

      if(value === 'true'){
            navigate to login
        }else{
            navigate to into 
             }
```

and in intro screen for the first time when you installed the app store value in asynstorage like

```
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("installSucess", "true");
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I ended up using `SwitchNavigation` and I followed their auth-flow.